# Repeats function until certain criteria is met? Google Sheets / Calendar API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Below is a script I currently run to download event data from Google Calendars. The way it's currently written, it: 1) Clears the sheet each time it's ran before populating with new data; 2) Runs once, on command, pulling the Calendar ID from a single cell (D2) value

I have about 8 different Cal ID's saved into a separate sheet called 'CalIDs', which I will copy/paste into cell D2 each time I run the script. Full process is: Paste first Cal ID, run script, copy data into another sheet, paste second Cal ID, run script, copy data into another sheet... repeat this process until all 8 Cal IDs have their data pulled and copied into the other sheet.

What I'd like to do is modify this script to have it run like this:
Reference cell A1 of 'CalIDs' sheet to pull first calendar's data, dump into sheet. Then check for value in A2 of CalIDs - if not empty, run script again pulling that 2nd calendar's data into the sheet, APPENDING to the existing data (not overwriting first data, so I imagine a "find first empty row" type of command is needed). Continue this process until the first empty cell of Col A on CalIDs is found, then end.

Any help on how to do this? I've searched around and have not found any answers myself.

```
  function CalendarDownload(){  

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('PULL'))

  var mycal = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("c2").getValue(); // PULL CALENDAR ID FROM CELL   
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
  var startdate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("a2").getValue()  // SET THE DATE OF SEARCH RANGE
  var enddate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("b2").getValue()   // SET THE DATE OF SEARCH RANGE
  var editor = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("d2").getValue()   // COLLECT CALENDER ID FROM CELL
  var events = cal.getEvents(startdate, enddate); // SET THE DATE OF SEARCH RANGE

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(4, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 9).clear({contentsOnly:true});

// Create a header record on the current spreadsheet in cells A1:N1 - Match the number of entries in the "header=" to the last parameter of the getRange entry below
var header = [["Event Start", "Event End", "Description", "EDITOR", "DURATION", "PROD #", "PHASE", "NOTES"]]
var range = sheet.getRange(3,1,1,8);
range.setValues(header);

// Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on calulated ROW 3 (i+3)
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
var row=i+4;
var myformula_placeholder = '';
var details=[[events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getTitle(), editor]];
var range=sheet.getRange(row,1,1,4);
range.setValues(details);

 var cell=sheet.getRange(row,5);
cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(B' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(B' +row+ ')/60))-(HOUR(A' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(A' +row+ ')/60))');
cell.setNumberFormat('.00');



}
}
```

Comment: There are absolutely questions here about determining the first empty row in a specific column. The Spreadsheet Service provides a useful sheet class method as well.

Comment: Yeah, to clarify my comment, I understand that code but can't figure out how it's used in a repeat/loop function. Happy to do the research just unsure where to start or what keywords to be hunting for here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd modify your code like this:

```
//******************************************************************************

function allCalendars(){
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var ss = sheet.getSheetByName('PULL');
      var os = sheet.getSheetByName('CalIds');
      var start = 2;
      ss.getRange(4, 1, ss.getLastRow(), 9).clear({contentsOnly:true});
      var data = os.getDataRange().getValues();
      for (var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
        {
            start = CalendarDownload(start,data[i][0]);
        }//for loop

}//*****************************************************************************
```

and then I modified CalendarDownload a little:

```
function CalendarDownload(start,mycal){  

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('PULL'))

  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
  var startdate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("a2").getValue()  // SET THE DATE OF SEARCH RANGE
  var enddate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("b2").getValue()   // SET THE DATE OF SEARCH RANGE
  var editor = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("d2").getValue()   // COLLECT CALENDER ID FROM CELL
  var events = cal.getEvents(startdate, enddate); // SET THE DATE OF SEARCH RANGE



// Create a header record on the current spreadsheet in cells A1:N1 - Match the number of entries in the "header=" to the last parameter of the getRange entry below
var header = [["Event Start", "Event End", "Description", "EDITOR", "DURATION", "PROD #", "PHASE", "NOTES"]]
var range = sheet.getRange(3,1,1,8);
range.setValues(header);

// Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on calulated ROW 3 (i+3)
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
var row=i+4;
var myformula_placeholder = '';
var details=[[events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getTitle(), editor]];
var range=sheet.getRange((start+row),1,1,4);
range.setValues(details);

 var cell=sheet.getRange(row,5);
cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(B' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(B' +row+ ')/60))-(HOUR(A' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(A' +row+ ')/60))');
cell.setNumberFormat('.00');

return sheet.getLastRow();


}
}
```

The first function loops through each calendar on the list, the second writes all the events and then passes back the starting row for the next calendar.